# Regd. LandScape page oriented when transformed using scale Instance

Tags: java, pdfbox

Greetings for the day :)

I am working on Apache PdfBox 2.0 and i transformed A0 and A1 Landscape document to A4 Portrait Page by using get scaling Instance and transform. I could achive that without lose of content present on A0/A1 Landscape page. But the issue here is the landscape document transformed to A4 portrait is shifted to second half of the PDF A4 Portrait Page . I am trying to move that to first half of the A4 portrait page but tried lot of approached such a rotation, trasformation...etc. But did not workout successfully. Can you please help me to move/transform the A0/A1 landscape page to first half on to A4 Portrait page.

```
PDPageContentStream cd = new PDPageContentStream(doc,currPage,AppendMode.PREPEND,false,false); 
tx = PDRectangle.A4.getUpperRightX()/currPage.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX();
ty = PDRectangle.A4.getUpperRightY()/currPage.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY(); 

if(tx <= ty){
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(tx,tx));
}else{
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(ty,ty));
}

currPage.setMediaPage(PDRectangle.A4);

contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
contentStream.close();

doc.adPage(currPage);
doc.save(filepath);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr , can you please check if you have a solution?

Comment: You should share the code that you used and the PDFs... I think you do need a translation, i.e. a vertical move.

Comment: Hi @Tilman Hausherr, i coded the following.                           
PDPageContentStream cd = new PDPageContentStream(doc,currPage,AppendMode.PREPEND,false,false); tx = PDRectangle.A4.getUpperRightX()/currPage.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX();ty = PDRectangle.A4.getUpperRightY()/currPage.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();    
 if(tx <= ty){contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(tx,tx));}else{contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(ty,ty));} currPage.setMediaPage(PDRectangle.A4);contentStream.saveGraphicsState();contentStream..close();doc.adPage(currPage);doc.save(filepath);

Comment: Hard to read, please edit your question. But from what I see, you're only scaling. Not translating.

Comment: Hi @Tilman Hausherr Edited, Please check

Comment: Yeah, you need to add an Y translation. Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, y); Not sure about y but you can find that out.